# Cauchy's formula on permutations

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, permutations

Statement:

> Let $k=(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)\in\mathbb N^n$. We say that a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ is of type $k$ if it has $k_1$ number of 1-cycles, ... , $k_n$ number of n-cycles. According to Cauchy, the number of such permutations is:
>   $n!/(k_1!*k_2!*...*k_n!*1^{k_1}*2^{k_2}*...*n^{k_n})$.

How do I prove this?
P.s.: I'm 11th grade and I'm at the beggining of permutations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Historical context : (http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/cauchy-permutations-origin-group-theory)

Comment: There are rather nice proofs involving probability (maybe, you haven't had lectures on this topic) as explained in this celebrated blog :(https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/the-number-of-cycles-in-a-random-permutation/)